What is the relationship between rational points and integer points on algebraic varieties?
Let $C$ be a plane conic defined over the integers by some equation $f(x,y)=0$. If $C$ has a rational point $P$, then in fact $C$ has infinitely many and all of them can be found by drawing lines with rational slope through $P$ and finding the other point of intersection.
This is a beautiful fact and when applied to the unit circle, $x^2+y^2=1$one can use this to find all integer solutions to the homogeneous equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and one can see for instance that there are infinitely many. This is a standard application in number theory.  But if we stick to the original eqution, note there are only finitely many integer points.
My question is how this generalizes.  For instance - the argument above shows why the equation $x^2-2y^2=1$ has infinitely many rational points. Coincidentally (?) it happens to have infinitely many integer points as well. (This is Pell's equation and its integer solutions can be described in a number of useful ways).
I don't see any reason there should be a connection between "has infinitely many rational points" and "has infinitely many integer points"  (consider a curve $2y^2 = 2x +1$ as an extreme case) but I'm wondering if maybe there's something that can be said or some partial result.
My application would be in higher degree, but I'm curious even for quadratic equations what is known.
To give a very specific version of my question: if one has a way to parametrize all rational points on an algebraic variety in terms of some rational parameters ($m_i$) when is it possible to describe the set of all integer points?  I'm thinking there might not be any hope since in the three examples on this post we saw that there can be 4, infinitely many, or no integer points. Thanks for any directions of where to look.

Edit your tag & Include a Diophantine equation Tag

Good idea, thank you

Thanks - really my integer points I just mean "solutions to the equation" rather than "points on the variety" and I realize they're slightly different. For the equations I'm looking at, I actually know they have infinitely many rational points. I should have mentioned that
